# Create A WorkSheet Array within a Workbook in c#

Tags: c#

```
static Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
static object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
static Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet;
```

I need to create xlwooksheet as array

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Get all all worksheets from a workbook?

Comment: I just want to declare an array of Worksheets within the workBook(xlworkbook) which i created....like i created xlworkSheet within the Xlworkbook now i need to declare an array of worksheets